# C# How to get tabs from chrome in multiple windows?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, tabs, window

So I have [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070703/how-to-get-a-list-of-open-tabs-from-chrome-c-sharp) that extracts all the tabs from a window of chrome.

However if I there are multiple windows open, only the most recent one is recognised.

Is it possible to extract the tabs from multiple windows instead of only the most recent one?

EDIT:
The code that I use and needs fixing:

```
public List<string> ChromeTabs()
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();

        Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

        if (procsChrome.Length <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Chrome is not running");
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Process proc in procsChrome)
            {
                // the chrome process must have a window 

                if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // to find the tabs we first need to locate something reliable - the 'New Tab' button 
                AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                Condition condNewTab = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "New Tab");
                AutomationElement elmNewTab = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, condNewTab);

                // get the tabstrip by getting the parent of the 'new tab' button 
                TreeWalker treewalker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
                AutomationElement elmTabStrip = treewalker.GetParent(elmNewTab); // <- Error on this line

                // loop through all the tabs and get the names which is the page title 
                Condition condTabItem = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem);
                foreach (AutomationElement tabitem in elmTabStrip.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, condTabItem))
                {
                    ret.Add(tabitem.Current.Name);
                    //Console.WriteLine(tabitem.Current.Name);
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }`
```

Comment: The code in the answer to your other question looks correct, it's enumerating all the chrome processes (since chrome is multi-process), and then grabbing the window handle. Due to the multi-process nature, I can't imagine one process would have multiple windows. When you say "most recent", do you mean the one in the foreground, or the last one you interacted with?

Comment: The last one interacted with

Comment: Can you show us your current code?

Comment: Does http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-can-i-get-title-of-a-chrome-processes help?

Comment: @mjwills The site currently gives me 503 status code so I'll try again later and get back to you.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 9):

I was also running into this issue where only the most recent used Google Chrome window was returning a non-zero `MainWindowHandle` which was in turn preventing me from getting tab information from other Google Chrome windows.

I ended up fixing this by enumerating through the desktop windows and finding the `Handle` of each Google Chrome process that adhered to a set of rules that I found (through hours of debugging) that reliably returns browser windows.

I was able to pass the `Handles` found during desktop window enumeration to the typical `AutomationElement` method used to get the tab information of *all* running Google Chrome windows.

```
delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(IntPtr hWnd, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, EnumWindowsProc ewp, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern bool GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, uint nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern uint GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

// get all the process id's of the running chrome processes
Process[] chromeProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
List<uint> chromeProcessIds = chromeProcesses.Select(x => (uint)x.Id).ToList();

// a list to store the handles of the Google Chrome windows that we'll find
List<IntPtr> windowHandles = new List<IntPtr>();

EnumWindowsProc enumerateHandle = delegate (IntPtr hWnd, int lParam)
{
    // get the id of the process of the window we are enumerating over
    uint id;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, out id);

    // if the process we're enumerating over has an id in our chrome process ids, we need to inspect it to see if it is a window or other process
    if (chromeProcessIds.Contains(id))
    {
        // get the name of the class of the window we are inspecting
        var clsName = new StringBuilder(256);
        var hasClass = GetClassName(hWnd, clsName, 256);
        if (hasClass)
        {
            // get the text of the window we are inspecting
            var maxLength = (int)GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
            var builder = new StringBuilder(maxLength + 1);
            GetWindowText(hWnd, builder, (uint)builder.Capacity);

            var text = builder.ToString();
            var className = clsName.ToString();

            // actual Google Chrome windows have text set to the title of the active tab
            // in my testing, this needs to be coupled with the class name equaling "Chrome_WidgetWin_1". 
            // i haven't tested this with other versions of Google Chrome
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) && className.Equals("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // if we satisfy the conditions, this is a Google Chrome window. Add the handle to the list of handles to use later.
                windowHandles.Add(hWnd);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
};

EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, enumerateHandle, 0);

foreach (IntPtr ptr in windowHandles)
{
    AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(ptr);
   
    // continue grabbing Chrome tab information using the AutomationElement method
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was debugging quite some time until I found this answer, works great! I wonder why it didn't get any upvotes yet

Comment: small typo there where unit should be uint

Comment: @Joe Thanks - I edited the answer and fixed the typo.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Thanks