# Error "Value can't be null", UIAutomationElement

Tags: c#, google-chrome, ui-automation

So I am trying to gett all the open tabs from Chrome using UIAutomation in C# but I keep getting the error:

> System.ArgumentNullException occurred
>
> HResult=0x80004003
>   Message=Value can't be NULL.
>   Source=UIAutomationClient
>
> StackTrace:
>   at System.Windows.Automation.TreeWalker.GetParent(AutomationElement element)
>   at chromeTabsTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users...\chromeTabsTest\chromeTabsTest\Program.cs:line 31

The error is indicated with a comment in the code.

```
    using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Automation;

namespace chromeTabsTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] procsChrome = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
            if (procsChrome.Length <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Chrome is not running");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Process proc in procsChrome)
                {
                    // the chrome process must have a window 
                    if (proc.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // to find the tabs we first need to locate something reliable - the 'New Tab' button 
                    AutomationElement root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                    Condition condNewTab = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "New Tab");
                    AutomationElement elmNewTab = root.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, condNewTab);
                    // get the tabstrip by getting the parent of the 'new tab' button 
                    TreeWalker treewalker = TreeWalker.ControlViewWalker;
                    AutomationElement elmTabStrip = treewalker.GetParent(elmNewTab); // <------------- Error here 
                    // loop through all the tabs and get the names which is the page title 
                    Condition condTabItem = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem);
                    foreach (AutomationElement tabitem in elmTabStrip.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, condTabItem))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(tabitem.Current.Name);
                    }
                }
            }


            Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This code is from another Stack Overflow question: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070703/how-to-get-a-list-of-open-tabs-from-chrome-c-sharp)

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: Your title says your error is "Value can't be null" - your question says "Value can't be negative". These seem to be two very different things. Which one is it?

Comment: Nobody has the time to analyse your code without any suggestion, in which line the error is thrown..

Comment: What is the **exact** error message (please copy and paste it, as you can't seem to get it straight when typing it)? And which line is raising the exception? (The stack trace tells you that, and you can also find it by stepping through the code in the debugger.)

Comment: Question edited I addressed all the comments. Thank you all for pointing theme out.

Comment: `System.ArgumentNullException` is pretty self explanatory. You have an argument that is null and this is not allowed. it tells you what line it is on, the method there only has one argument so that argument must be null.  This is all spelt out to you. What is your actual question?

Comment: @Chris I understand what the problem is, i can't figure out the solution. This code is supposed to work I also linked to the origin of this code. Could you please run the code at least.

Comment: @user6879072: The linked question that has this code has you complaining about the same issue on it (ArgumentNullException being thrown). Did you not get it resolved at that time?

Comment: There is a deleted answer on that question that might hold the answer: "it wants to find "New Tab",and it can't find it, for me but i think for you too is for the following reason: that string is localized, so if you have a non eglish crome, it will be the "New Tab" string translated to that language."

Comment: @Chris No, but than I seen similar questions on different forums and people link back to that question as the solution. Like this one: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/eaef0ea6-9426-45ca-a5f0-b9bc5c53b84e/how-to-get-all-open-tabs-in-google-chrome?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @Chris You are a genius... It was the translation that caused the issue

Comment: @user6879072: Cool. I'm glad I went to look at that other question then. :) I've upgraded the comment to an answer so that it can be accepted and we have a nice reliable answer for anybody else suffering similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the following line is language sensitive:

```
Condition condNewTab = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "New Tab");
```

That is to say that "New Tab" rather than being an internal field is a localised string. This means that this line must be updated to have the correctly localised version of this text.

It is quite possible that there is a better "locate something reliable" that could be used but I am not familiar enough with chrome automation to be able to say if there is and if so what.