# Activate tab in opened Browser (Opera/Chrome)

Tags: c#, google-chrome, tabs, opera

I'm programming an application which should help our users to manage opened windows. I created a mainwindow with buttons. On this the user can click a button to maximize each application they're using.

The users also work with different web applications which are opened in different browsertabs.

I'd like to activate/select an opened tab in Opera & Google Chrome.

This question helped me to find the opened tabs: [How to get a list of open tabs from chrome? | C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070703/how-to-get-a-list-of-open-tabs-from-chrome-c-sharp)

I tried the following:

- Set focus on a tab with the method "SetFocus" of the Automation Element.
- Get a point on the tab and simulate a mouseclick on it.
- Simulate the buttonpress "control + Tab" to go through the opened tabs.

Some code snippets to the code of the link above:

```cs
foreach (AutomationElement tabitem in elmTabStrip.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, condTabItem))
{
//open the browser by the process id of the browsertab
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.AppActivate(tabitem.Current.ProcessId);

//Simulate buttonpress to change the tab
SendKeys.SendWait("^+{Tab}");

//select a specific tabs
tabitem.SetFocus();
}
```

Comment: Today I tried to made an UI Test and integrat it in my code. When i'm starting my application i receive a FileNotFound-Exception. Think VisualStudio removes the UI-Test-Dependencys.