# How to get URLs opened in all the browsers running on PC using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

I tried below code but it returns only the title (i.e not the url) of currently active tab on browser.

```
public void TrackUrls()
{
    List<string> browsers = new List<string>() { "Google Chrome", "Microsoft Edge" };

    foreach (var item in browsers) 
    {
        Process[] arrprocesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(item);

        foreach (Process pro in arrprocesses)
        {
            if (pro.MainWindowTitle.Length != 0)
                File.AppendAllText(appDataPath + @"\Sleep\\sleep.text", "      "+pro.MainWindowTitle + "\r\n")//here we are saving data in file;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code returns the title of a process's window. It knows nothing about tabs and URLs. A process object doesn't store such information

Comment: What are you trying to do? Normally you can't control browsers or read information from them unless you configure them for debugging or automation (eg through Selenium) through command line arguments

Comment: see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070703/how-to-get-a-list-of-open-tabs-from-chrome-c-sharp